# React native header gets cut off when keyboard is up

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, responsiveness

My react native header gets pushed up and some parts of it gets cut off when the keyboard is up. On smaller screens like iphone SE this prevents users from pressing CTA buttons. When I background and foreground the app the header is no longer cut off but I'm not sure how to fix this programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and styling

Comment: did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeAreaView from `react-native`.

`import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';`

You can wrap your components with SafeAreaView.

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview